# How to read a csv/txt file from gcs bucket using Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch, google-cloud-storage

I want to **read a csv/txt file from GCP Storage Bucket** using **Spring Batch**.

What are the dependency needed?

Please guide me how to achieve this.